# Angular menu items with attached dropdowns doesn't display at all

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, nested

I'm making an angular menu which is pretty complex (or will be later on), I've done most of the structuring but I'm stuck on this one thing. As you can see I have specified different menu options for different people depending on who's currently logged in. Right now I just want to show the menu for the "admin". I've put an `ng-if` that checks for an `admin` property, if it find one it should loop out it's contents as a main li item along with an ul containing the dropdown list items. However the way I've done it it shows everything excepts the `admin` content.. I've been trying different solutions for hours but I just can't get it right. What am I doing wrong?

I apologize for a lot of code but it's necessary to get a good overview of the structure I have.

```
<header>
    <ul id="main-menu">
        <li data-ng-repeat="menu in menus" id="{{menu.id}}"><a href="{{menu.URL}}.php">{{menu.title}}</a>
            <ul data-ng-repeat="submenu in menu" data-ng-if="menu.admin"> <--if admin
                <li data-ng-repeat="subitem in submenu.items"><a href="{{subitem.URL}}.php">{{subitem.title}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

This is my controller containing all the information:

```
onlinePlatform.controller('onlinePlatformCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.menus = [

        {
            title: 'Startsida',
            URL: 'home'
        },
        {
            title: 'Nyheter',
            URL: 'news'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meddelanden',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Inkorg',
                    URL: 'inbox'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Skickade meddelanden',
                    URL: 'sentmsg'
                },
                {   
                    title: 'Borttagna meddelanden',
                    URL: 'removedmsg'
                }
            ],
            URL: 'messages',
            id: 'msg'
        },
        {
            admin: {
                        title: 'Administration',
                        items: [
                            {
                                title: 'Hantera utbildningar',
                                URL: 'mngprograms'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Hantera kurser',
                                URL: 'mngcourses'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Hantera lärare',
                                URL: 'mngteachers'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Hantera studenter',
                                URL: 'mngstudents'
                            }
                        ],
                        URL: 'administration',
                        id: 'administration'
            },
            teacher: {
                        title: 'Utbildning',
                        items: [
                            {
                                title: 'Kurser överblick',
                                URL: 'coursesoverview'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Sätt eller ändra betyg',
                                URL: 'editgrades'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Boka eller avboka lokaler',
                                URL: 'classroombooking'
                            }
                        ],
                        URL: 'utbildning',
                        id: 'utbildning'
            },
            student: {
                        title: 'Mina sidor',
                        items: [
                            {
                                title: 'Mina kurser',
                                URL: 'mycourses'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Mitt schema',
                                URL: 'myschedule'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Mina betyg',
                                URL: 'mygrades'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Mina kontaktuppgifter',
                                URL: 'mycontactinfo'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Klasslista',
                                URL: 'classlist'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Anteckningar',
                                URL: 'notes'
                            }
                        ],
                        URL: 'mypages',
                        id: 'mypages'
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'Forum',
            URL: 'forum'
        },
        {
            title: 'Kalender',
            URL: 'calendar'
        },
        {
            admin: {
                title: 'Enkäter',
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Skapa enkät',
                        URL: 'createsurvey'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Visa tidigare enkäter',
                        URL: 'previussurveys'
                    }
                ],
                URL: 'surveys',
                id: 'surveys'
            },
            teacher: {
                title: 'Kontaktuppgifter',
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Profil',
                        URL: 'profile'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Redigera kontaktuppgifter',
                        URL: 'editcontactinfo'
                    }
                ],
                URL: 'contactinfo',
                id: 'contactinfo'
            },
            student: {
                title: 'Verktyg',
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Ladda ner Dreamspark produkter',
                        URL: 'dreamspark'
                    }
                ],
                URL: 'tools',
                id: 'tools'
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'Hjälp',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Vanliga frågor',
                    URL: 'faq'
                },
                {
                    title: 'JENSEN kontaktuppgifter',
                    URL: 'contactinfo'
                }
            ],
            URL: 'help',
            id: 'help'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: data-ng-if ??? did you create a costume directive called that? because as far as I know there is no data-ng-if. did you mean to use ng-if?

Comment: @RiceJunkie data-ng-if is a directive which makes it HTML5 compatible or whatever. It's the same as ng-if, it says somewhere on their website can't remember where though.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, `ng-show=menu.admin`. However, it's advised to use a method rather than just an assignment to check the authorization to show/hide elements, as the method will wait until Angular resolves it's value but the variable just consider it's current status to show/hide the element.

Comment: Instead of `data-ng-if="menu.admin"` use the `ng-show="menu.admin"`